# Select all fields within database of certain datatype

Tags: sql

I am looking for an sql script which can select all fields in a database which are of a particualr datatype.

I have looked all over stack overflow and various pages i have found in google but yet no avail!

Maybe I am looking in the wrong places.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting one, my first question would have to be why are you trying to do this? Perhaps there is a better way..

Comment: I have to manage 4 identical SQL servers which are all out of sync and I need to convert all datetime2 datatypes to datetime. I have the rest of the sql code which will do the conversion, the answer below is perfect. Feel a bit embarrassed its so simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you list of all the fields to of perticular data type in a data base with table name may be you can work around this.

SELECT * FROM .INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE=''

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was going to be more complicated than that!

Comment: Welcome!You can find other tables unders information_Schema, if you wanna try something more. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
USE DatabaseName;
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG
    ,TABLE_SCHEMA
    ,TABLE_NAME
    ,COLUMN_NAME
    ,DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE DATA_TYPE LIKE 'varchar' --Or other Data Type
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can try select by type.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_TYPE = 'datetime';
```